# How to create IOS Simulator Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am a newbie for the flutter Using AndroidStudio as IDE. 
I successfully create the Flutter Application and able to run it on Android emulator.

Can I create IOS simulator to test the Application using Android studio? If Yes Please suggest how it is possible?

Comment: On which system? Because apart from Mac System, you will not be able to create iOS Simulator

Comment: yes I am working with Mac OS and Android Studio

Comment: Install XCode and you will be able to create a simulator.

Comment: That is the same issue as I answered in another stack. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017002/7735965

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open iOS Simulator in Android Studio for Flutter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745783/how-to-open-ios-simulator-in-android-studio-for-flutter-application)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, I'm using Android Studio with IOS Simulator. Open the simulator in your mac and you can show device in Android Studio.

You can open simulator only with this command

`open -a Simulator`

And you will show the **iPhone** device in Android Studio when the simulator opened.

[image]

Comment: can we use ios simulator on windows or linux platform for flutter in android studio?

Comment: @MMK no. You can't use iOS simulator on windows or linux platform. If you want to use this, you can look at the online simulator services. I didn't try it before but it's the only way.

Comment: did you download the simulator? if yes then how? or did it come when you install flutter and dart plugin in android studio. @Anilcan

Answer (score 1):

- [image]Open your terminal and type only "open -a Simulator" that it.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS simulator is part of XCode and only runs on Apple OSX

See also https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/simulator_help_topics/Chapter/Chapter.html

Comment: I am working on Apple OSX I have running IOS simulator so is it possible to show that emulator into my listing of emulators I am not able to see like this https://flutter.io/images/intellij/main-toolbar.png

Comment: What do you get when you run `flutter devices`? Is the iOS simulator listed?